# Double launchers and mouse captured between screens in Twinview configuration

Tags: unity, 12.04

Just upgraded to 12.04 and noticed an extremely annoying issue.

While using twinview, there now appears to be a launcher on each screen. Moving the mouse between monitors and over the launcher "captures" the mouse for half a second or so, creating the perception of lag.

According to some bug reports I've read it appears that a launcher on every screen is a new "feature".

Is there any way I can get rid of the 2nd launcher? It's driving my crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an option in the system settings. It's found under monitors or under apperance (I'm not sure because it only shows if you have two monitors)

Comment: I think it used to, however I should clarify that I'm using an Nvidia card, so 'Displays' doesn't exactly function correctly.

I'll upload a screenshot

Comment: http://imgur.com/nVa1O

Comment: But if it identifies your second monitor (what it must else there was no second launcher) the option also has to show up... Are you sure there is no option?

Comment: Just realized thanks to jP_wanN that "sticky edges" is the issue that I'm having. It seems that there is a bug when it's enabled...it ignores launcher placement.

Thanks for getting me to that screen jP :)

Disabling sticky edges stops the lag

Comment: You can see in the screenshot that it only sees one gigantic screen :(

Comment: Yeah, I heard of some dirty workaround with nVidia twinview I think that's it, isn't it? EDIT: Oh it's in the title :D
Which driver do you use?

Comment: Stuck with the binary blog

Comment: This is not the correct answer for me!! :-( I do not even have the Displays section under System Settings! What can I do? It is driving me crazy? Who has such STUPID ideas to enable by default? I got Nvidia twinview enabled - but there I don't find sticky edges! PLEASE HELP!

Comment: So you also have Ubuntu (not Kubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) 12.04, two monitors and a nVidia graphics card with TwinView, and this is enabled. And you can't find "Monitors" in your System Settings (under Hardware, it's a black monitor icon with a yellow set square)?

Answer (score 4):

It's under System Settings, Display, Sticky Edges. You have to set this to off.

Comment: You're a little late to the party, but thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You also have to set 'Edge stop velocity" (in CCSM) to something very low but greater than 1.

For an idea of suitable values:

- At "1", neither launcher appears, at a high value the launcher in the middle absorbs some of the momentum from the mouse so although not sticky it does cause a momentary check to movement.
- At "3", which I use, it is no longer a nuisance, I'd recommend a simlar choice of number.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question: You can't disable the second launcher, because Unity fails to detect your Twinview configuration. If it were detecting it you would have an option to choose where to show the launcher in your *Display* configuration.

For reference: I'm having the same issue and it seems to be a know problem.